# How to turn off EDP on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, efs

Since Windows 10 automatically updated to the latest version (November 2015 update I believe), all my EFS files are flagged with a lock icon. And when I copy an EFS-encrypted file to a FAT drive, it gets a .PFILE extension and remains encrypted. This breaks my workflow.

Googling, I've found that this is called [Enterprise Data Protection](http://ronnydejong.com/2015/11/09/enterprise-data-protection-under-the-hood/) and apparently it can be turned off. Does anyone know how to do this? I couldn't find it in the article neither in the linked TechNet article.

Comment: It seems like Windows 10 can now use EFS on non-NTFS drives. Try maybe to use the [cipher tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on this FAT folder with the `/D` flag, if it still exists in Windows 10. Be careful, because I think that the description of this flag is mangled. Better use it on a FAT drive that you don't care about.

Comment: That would be a way to decrypt the files on the FAT drive afterwards, but knowing cipher it should take a LOOONG time. I'd rather copy them without encryption in the first place. Should be possible to just turn of EDP right?

Comment: Try in registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\EnterpriseDataProtection\Policies` to set `EDPEnforcementLevel` to 0 (Off), reboot before testing.

Comment: @harrymc: That doesn't work, oddly enough. Tried both `DWORD (32-bit)` and string values. I've also tried the same in the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\DataProtection` key, but no luck either.

Comment: I'd think there should be a setting somewhere in the Group Policy Editor right?

Comment: There is, but it seems it's only for Windows 10 Enterprise ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn904962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Examination shows that EDP is enormous ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx)), and supposedly can be driven by the manifest file, but not much information. It seems like Microsoft has built an incredibly restrictive mechanism *and set it in motion, without providing documentation or tools*. Just typical. Frankly, this is probably a bullet in Microsoft's other leg. Suggestion: downgrade to Windows 7.

Comment: Yes it seems huge. So odd that Microsoft just enables it in an update that is installed without your consent, provides almost no documentation, and makes it impossible to turn it off.

Comment: The next update will hopefully undo that, but until then I can't think of another solution except downgrading.